# What's the difference between javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:2.1 and org.mortbay.jetty:jsp-api-2.1:6.1.5?

Tags: jetty

I am cleaning up a build system for a product that uses Jetty. Currently the project has

```
javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:2.1
```

as a dependency. Given that I am using Jetty for my project I suspect using

```
org.mortbay.jetty:jsp-api-2.1:6.1.5
```

would be the better option. Am I right/wrong? Can they be used interchangeably? Does `jsp-api-2.1` leverage a different implementation? Or is it simply a repackage if `jsp-api` to assert compatibility with Jetty?

I've been trying to find information about this on the web, so far nothing has come up.

**Update**: Seems like `org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api-2.5:6.1.5` and `javax.servlet.jsp:servlet-api:2.1` have the same relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jetty has a long and colorful history with jsp, having no jsp implementation of our own we have leveraged other implementations often, judging by the version numbers your looking at those are very old versions where we were maintaining patches on top of the glassfish jsp implementation.  I think it was a patch for supporting logging in jetty and then a bug fix or three.

Now a days we have been using the jsp artifacts from the java.net project which was spun out from glassfish a while back.  However that doesn't seem to be tracking bug fixes very regularly either so we are kicking around trying the jasper implementation in tomcat.

Back on your question, the jsp-api artifacts are typically just repackaged artifacts since the api doesn't change frequently.  We historically rebundled them to keep them paired with the patched implementation.

Now, you are obviously using a jetty-6 setup since your still using org.mortbay packaging but jetty6 and jetty7 are both servlet-api 2.5 so you might be able to get away with using the jetty7 jsp setup, we have a handy pom that declares these artifacts here:

http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-jsp/7.6.5.v20120716/jetty-jsp-7.6.5.v20120716.pom

These are glassfish bundles as well, repackaged and made into osgi bundles in the process so they can be used with jetty in osgi environments....they ought to work normally though, we package them in our jetty7 distributions.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer this!